# Cannot contact Firebase support in new Firebase console

Tags: firebase

I cannot submit a request to support in the firebase console.

- Log into Firebase console
- Navigate to https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/
- Fill out all of the fields and hit Send. (We're trying to submit a ticket about Firebase Auth).

**Expected:** The ticket is submitted.
**Observed:** I'm getting an error message that reads, "Error Submitting request. Please try again later." This has been happening for several days.

We have tried with multiple users on our team, including the project owners. Each of our users has several "questions remaining."

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Comment: *firebaser here* Thanks for reporting this. We've had a few reports from people hitting this problem and are trying to figure out what may be causing it (e.g. I was able to submit a case over the weekend and just submitted one again). Do you have any additional details on the problem? Is there anything showing in the developer console, maybe a relevant error/response on the network tab? Anything you can tell me may help us find the cause of this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen additional details: the urgency was set to "high" and we were trying to submit a request about "Authorization." I received the issue both with and without a file attachment. The issue was experienced on multiple machines in Los Angeles and Reno.

Comment: I just got some more information on this and it seem related to having (certain) unicode characters in an attachment. A potential fix is being rolled out at the moment. If the problem persists and the issue is still urgent, try submitting the form without an attachment and then add the attachment in the email thread later. Sorry for the crappy workaround, but that should at least get the information about your actual problem into the system. Thanks again for reporting this, very helpful!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks! For what it's worth, I was copying text from Evernote or Flowdock and pasting it into the form each time I go the error.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue and I have a Critical support ticket to submit. This is a really bad situation to be in.

Comment: @Frank:
I just had the same issue with a bug report of mine and after reading your comments about file attachments I have replaced the 6 files that I had attached with a single .zip that contained all of them. With the .zip attachment I could successfully submit. The files have been 2 *.pcap, 2 *.mp4 and 2 *.txt files.

Comment: This issue is happening again to me right now and seems to happen regardless of the content of the support request or its attached files

Comment: It's 2019 and I have the same issue. I've stripped my report from all special characters, but still couldn't send it. Finally, I started over and didn't attach log file (just 5kb) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I copied code from Xcode into the support request  "Description" field. To fix it, I removed my code and placed it into a separate text file and attached it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for **Phone auth help.**

In **Phone Numbers** field,  Please try to add phone numbers with country code.

Example:

I was trying without country code like 9898989898. and **didn't work.**

Then I tried with +619898989898. and **IT WORKED.**

- You can try to remove special characters from the description as well.